# Solve the Angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

My background in Trigonometry and Geometry is very basic. 
I am doing a a study and need to work out the angle of a wire; I would also like to know it relative to vertical. I have attached a basic sketch with ?? indicating the angle in question.[image]
I'm unsure if this can even be done but thought I would throw it out and see!

Comment: I am sure that this question is off-topic here. However, as it is formulated it has no solution, since the position of the triangle is not fixed with respect to the horizontal line.

Comment: Thanks for the help. (new to the site)

Answer (score 2):

There is no unique solution for the angle measure. This is because we have no information relating the angles in the triangle to the perpendicular lines in the figure. If you sweep the triangle counterclockwise, you will see that this angle is variable.